# Site links blocked by Google Chrome 33 pop-up blocker

Tags: google-chrome

After Google Chrome 33 upgrade, I've noticed that all my site's links are blocked by the browser pop-up blocker. The links were working properly on Google Chrome 32 or older and not blocked. This is kind of strange for me as a piece of code like

```
<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
```

on the page is also blocked!

I have links like

```
<a id="some-id" class="mycred-points-link" href="http://example.com" title="Something" target="_blank" data-key="rsa-key">Somewhere</a>
```

on my page and I use myCRED Wordpress plugin to reward points to users when they click on links.

How can I find out what causes this issue?

Comment: What do your "site links" look like, how are popups triggered? Does the code you have given trigger any JS event handlers / popups? To be honest, I've not noticed anything different with Chrome 33 in this respect.

Comment: @w3d yes I have added my links code in the question.

Comment: What if you disable JavaScript?

Comment: When I disable javascript, it's not blocked anymore.

Comment: So I assume your popup capability is simply provided by the `target="_blank"` attribute? You aren't using JS to generate a popup? In that case it would seem that your WordPress plugins that (I assume) attach JS event handlers to those anchors are causing problems for the popup-blocker!?

Comment: yes it seems so. when I remove `target="_blank"` it's OK obviously.

Comment: @Pazis You might get more responses over at Super User since this is in regards to browser functionality. Would you like me to migrate it there, or leave it here?